# Navigation controller for ios8

Tags: objective-c

I have an app that post some data to the web service from a different view and if posted successfully it should navigate to another view. It freezes my app when Im trying to push to the success view, this is the code i used below for IOS8

```
MyLeadsViewController *homeView = [[MyLeadsViewController alloc] init];
homeView = (MyLeadsViewController*)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyLeadsViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:homeView animated:YES];
```

Comment: "Freezes the app" is never enough. You should add an exception breakpoint and tell what you get with the error message.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the Storyboard ID using the interface builder. Select your Navigation Controller, and in the right side bar enter your Storyboard ID - e.g. 'MyLeadsViewController'

This line

```
[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyLeadsViewController"];
```

looks for a View(Controller) inside your storyboard with the given Storyboard ID. So try this, I think that's responsible for your app freeze.